# flutter-graphql : how to mock watchQuery

Tags: flutter, mockito, flutter-graphql

I am trying to add a stub to mock flutter-graphql `watchQuery` results to in a unit test but it seems complex because `watchQuery` returns an `ObservableQuery` which depends on `QueryManager`.

```
ObservableQuery watchQuery(WatchQueryOptions options) {
    options.policies =
        defaultPolicies.watchQuery.withOverrides(options.policies);
    return queryManager.watchQuery(options);
  }
```

Can someone provide an example for a watchQuery stub?

Comment: Any luck on this @Asmaa?

Comment: @WiFi yeah, we used mockito's `@GenerateMocks(<Type>[ObservableQuery])` to mock it. and then the stub would look something like this:

`when(yourGraphqlClient.watchQuery(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => yourMockObservableQueryObject);`